# How do MySQL use multi-field indexes for queries with OR in the middle index field?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, innodb

I have InnoDB table Items with multi-column non-unique index (group_id, type_id, expiry_date).

In case of making query

`SELECT * FROM Items WHERE group_id = 1 AND type_id IN (1,2,3) AND expiry_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'`

Will index work fine as I'm using `IN` for second field of index and them additionally have range for 3rd will or I should benefit from spitting it to?

`SELECT * FROM Items WHERE group_id = 1 AND type_id = 1 AND expiry_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'
UNION
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE group_id = 1 AND type_id = 2 AND expiry_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'
UNION
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE group_id = 1 AND type_id = 3 AND expiry_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'`

EXPLAIN shows identical query plans for both queries, but I have quite a small table for testing and not sure if query optimiser will act same way on big amount of data.

And how in general does index works for case using `IN/OR/BETWEEN` on 2 consequent field in index?

Comment: Generate an execution plan for both and see for yourself. My hunch is IN is a lot faster then using union, while union all should be close or faster then IN.

Comment: Your first query with 'IN' should be able to use that index and behave much faster than second one even in case of huge data.

Comment: Please show _us_ the `EXPLAINs`.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

For your second query, use `union all` rather than `union`.  You always want `union all`, unless you want to incur overhead for removing duplicates.

I would guess that you would benefit from the second query on larger data.  I don't think MySQL supports skip-scans on indexes, so the index is only being used to `group_id` and `type_id`, but not directly for date.

Answer (score 0):

What version of MySQL/MariaDB?  There have been Optimizations recently; don't now if they would help here.

You have a possible bug -- in including an extra day in `AND expiry_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'`.  Change to

```
AND expiry_date >= '2017-01-01'
AND expiry_date  < '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

(This count as a single 'range' test.  `BETWEEN` is also a range test, but it is 'inclusive', hence the 'bug'.)

I would simply have two composite indexes (if I could not find the real answer to your Question):

```
(group_id, type_id, expiry_date)
(group_id, expiry_date)
```

Case 1:  The Optimizer can get past `IN`:  then the first index works.

Case 2:  The optimizer cannot get past `IN`:  Then one of these happens:

- The `IN` list has only one item.  Then it is converted from `IN` to `=`, and the first index is optimal, with all 3 columns used.
- The optimizer decides the first index is better -- small IN list, large date range.
- The optimizer decides that the date range is better (smaller range) and picks the second index.

The `UNION` approach may or may not be better in this situation.  There is a lot of overhead of gathering the data into a temp table.  The temp table was recently eliminated, but only for certain cases of `UNION ALL`.

Yes, use `UNION ALL`.  That eliminates an sort and possibly an extra temp table.

Test with a large dataset.  For under 1K rows, the performance is not likely to matter.

Rule of Thumb in ordering columns in an index:

1. `=` test(s)
2. `IN`, if any
3. *one* 'range' (`BETWEEN`, `<`, etc), if any
4. Consider making a "covering" index.

My [*Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

There are other optimizations that depend on what is in the `*` in `SELECT *`.